# Filter by object field in django-graphene

Tags: python, django, filter, graphql, graphene-python

I am writing a web application using `django-graphene`.
I try to filter by my models fields.

Models:

```
class Tire(models.Model):
    width = models.IntegerField()

class Spec(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.TextField()
    tire = models.ForeignKey(Tire)
```

Types:

```
class TireType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = data.models.Tire
        filter_fields = {
            'width': integer_filters
        }

class SpecType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = data.models.Spec
        filter_fields = {
            'manufacturer': string_filters
            'tire__width': integer_filters
        }
```

From this models and types I can filter by the fields (using the arithmetic operations `gt`, `lt` etc...).
I want to filter by an object (graphene field maybe?), so instead of:

```
{
  allTires(width_gt: 5
           width_lt: 10) { ... }
}
```

I want to execute this:

```
{
  allTires(input: { width_gt: 5
                    width_lt: 10
                  }) { ... }
}
```

Finally I want to achieve nested filters for foreign keys, for example:

```
{
  allSpecs(manufacturer: "toyota"
           tireFilter: {
             width_gt: 5
             width_lt: 10
           })} { ... }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I am trying to do something similar.. however I have a slightly different structure syntax: https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/273

Comment: Did you find an answer for the nested filters? would you mind providing your answers here? thanks

Comment: Have you found the answer?